# uploading files in php using xampp

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a problem in uploading files using php in XAMPP

my code is:

```
    include 'header.html';
include 'header.php';
include 'debugging.php';
echo '<br />';
echo '<h1> Upload files</h>';

echo <<<_END
<br/>
<form method='post' action='FileUpload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='100' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='1' />
</form>
<br/>

_END;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    if ($_FILES && $_FILES['filename']['name']) {
        $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['name']);
        $extension = $file_info['extension'];

        include 'DO_Files.php';

        $valid = DO_File::validExtension($extension);
        echo '1';
        if ($valid) {
            echo '2';
            $tmpName = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

            $name = "Files//" . $_FILES['filename']['name'];

            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name)) {
                echo '3';
                echo "<p>there was an error..</p>";
                echo error_get_last();
            } else {
                echo '4';
                $file = new DO_File();
                $file->FileName = $name;
                $file->FileSize = $_FILES['filename']['size'];

                if ($file->save()) {
                    echo '5';
                    echo $file->FileName;
                } else {
                    echo '6';
                    mysqli_error($file->dbc);
                }
            }
        }  else {
            echo '7';
        echo '<p>the file is not prompted</p>';}
        }  else {
            echo '8';
            echo 'no filee';    
        }
    }

    include 'footer.html';
```

I don't know why it doesn't upload. it works in remote server but with local server like XAMPP it shows an error on

```
 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name)) {
```

any help? because I didn't figure put how to upload files to loacl server

I made a directory and the permissions are fine.

Comment: It would also be really helpfull if we know what the error message is

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_array($_FILES['filename']) && $_FILES['filename']['error'] == 0) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        $sourcePath = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $targetPath = "Files//" . $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        if (!is_dir('Files//')) {
            mkdir('Files/', 0777, true);
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)) {
            echo $targetPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the mkdir works fine but now it shows me that MYSQL server has gone away.